# Extract Text from PDF and Save Extracted Text in Excel or Elsewhere

Tags: pdf, uipath

I am not a professional programmer. I would like a simple way to extract text from pdf and save the text into Excel.

I think Uipath can extract text using OCR. But I don't think that is a very reliable way.

1. Can I use Uipath to do the text extraction via a more reliable way other than OCR?
2. Can I use Python, R or other user-friendly software to extract the text from pdf?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The UiPath OCR capabilities are very capable when the PDF or image being processed is of high quality. However, it performs poorly on low resolution text. If OCR is your only option on low quality quality artifacts, you'll want to use a sophisticated AI offering such as Google Cloud Vision as your OCR tool of choice. I compared [UiPath vs Cloud Vision](https://youtu.be/y-Yi9f4AnQA) and the difference was stark.

### Tagged vs Untagged PDFs

Check to see if the PDF document you are using is tagged or not. You can view this by looking at the document properties, as in this example:

[image]

### Better than OCR

If your PDF is tagged, you can use the [UiPath Anchor Base](https://youtu.be/rjtHXD2nI8Q) activity to extract name-value pairs. And you can perform a structured [UiPath data scrape](https://youtu.be/6c1Tda0F0WI) to extract tabular list type data. The results from these extractions will be very high quality and much easier to work with than a full page scrape or OCR.

### Save to Excel

As for the need to save to Excel, UiPath has many built in features for working with Excel, spreadsheets and CSV files in general. The basic process is this:

1. Scrape the data
2. Store the scraped text in a DataTable
3. Create an Excel Application Scope activity
4. Append the DataTable to the Excel file

Here's a simple example of a UiPath Studio project that does exactly that:

[image]

As you can see from the image above, the data is scraped, the DataTable is iterated over and finally [UiPath saves to Excel](https://youtu.be/QjDV38pqhqs):

Answer (score 0):

**OCR** is the way to go when **extracting text from a PDF** file.

Answering #1: Simply use the `Read PDF Files` activity, [more infos](https://docs.uipath.com/activities/docs/read-pdf-with-ocr)

Answering #2: Sure there are many way to extract PDFs. You can use any technology you want. But you won't have big success **without** using OCR. Using UiPath is the easiest as you already have the precompiled activities that you can freely choose from.

And do not forget to play around with the different OCR tech of `OCRTesseract`, `OCRMicrosoft` and `OCRGoogle`.